# C# static class constructor

Tags: c#, class, static, constructor

Is there a work around on how to create a constructor for static class?

I need some data to be loaded when the class is initialized but I need one and only one object.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

C# has a static constructor for this purpose.

```
static class YourClass
{
    static YourClass()
    {
        // perform initialization here
    }
}
```

**From MSDN**:

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to
>   perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It
>   is called automatically before the first instance is created or any
>   static members are referenced

[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)

.

Comment: Note that there's no requirement that `YourClass` be `static`.

Comment: To be fair, the original poster did specifically ask about a constructor for a static class.

Answer (score 47):

A static constructor looks like this

```
static class Foo
{
    static Foo()
    {
         // Static initialization code here
    }
}
```

It is executed only once when the type is first used. All classes can have static constructors, not just static classes.

Comment: Actually "It is called automatically BEFORE the first instance is created or any static members are referenced"  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a static class can have static constructor, and the use of this constructor is initialization of static member.

```
static class Employee1
{
    static int EmpNo;
    static Employee1()
    {
        EmpNo = 10;
        // perform initialization here
    }
    public static void Add()
    { 

    }
    public static void Add1()
    { 

    }
}
```

and static constructor get called only once when you have access any type member of static class with class name **Class1**

Suppose you are accessing the first EmployeeName field then constructor get called this time, after that it will not get called, even if you will access same type member.

```
 Employee1.EmployeeName = "kumod";
        Employee1.Add();
        Employee1.Add();
```

Answer (score 2):

`Static constructor` called only the first instance of the class created.

like this:

```
static class YourClass
{
    static YourClass()
    {
        //initialization
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create static constructor

```
static class StaticParent 
{
  StaticParent() 
  {
    //write your initialization code here

  }

}
```

and it is always parameter less.

```
static class StaticParent
{
    static int i =5;
    static StaticParent(int i)  //Gives error
    {
      //write your initialization code here
    }
}
```

and it doesn't have the access modifier

Answer (score 0):

You can use static constructor to initialization  static variable. Static constructor will be entry point for your class

```
public class MyClass
{

    static MyClass()
    {

        //write your initialization code here
    }

}
```

Comment: static constructor doesn't have the access modifier, this will be a compilation error

Answer (score 0):

Static classes cannot have instance constructors (unlike the accepted answer).  However, a class can have a static constructor. That is totally different.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 9, there is [ModuleInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/module-initializers) attribute which is much better than static constructors. The advantages are listed below as quoted from the linked site:

> - Enable libraries to do eager, one-time initialization when loaded,    with minimal overhead and without the user needing to explicitly call anything
> - One particular pain point of current static constructor approaches is that the runtime must do additional checks on usage of a type with a static constructor, in order to decide whether the static constructor needs to be run or not. This adds measurable overhead.
> - Enable source generators to run some global initialization    logic without the user needing to explicitly call anything

These are super-important points and one can use the attribute like the following in their static class:

```
[ModuleInitializer]
public static void Init()
{
    // Logic
}
```

Comment: valid for NET 6 ?