# How to create Application variable in .Net Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0, application-variables

I have created website using `.Net Core 2.0`. Now I want to store some values which are not user specific, I want to make those value shareable across all the users which are logged in. So for that I can use `Application Variable`. But in `.Net Core 2.0` there is no built in way to achieve this.

**What I have tried**

I have created one class as below.

```
public class ApplicationLevelData
    {
        public Guid TestProperty { get; set; }

        public ApplicationLevelData()
        {
            TestProperty = Guid.NewGuid(); // this data will comes from database (only once)
        }
    }
```

After that under `Startup.cs` file under `ConfigureServices` method I have wrote below line.

`services.AddSingleton<ApplicationLevelData>();`

And in each `Controller` I need to inject that service as below.

private ApplicationLevelData _appData;

```
public HomeController(ApplicationLevelData appData)
{
    _appData = appData;
}
```

And after that we can user that in entire `Controller`.

**But,** I don't want this `Inject` thing. Can we make application data available using `HttpContext`?

Can anyone suggest me the way that how can I create `Application variable` in `.Net Core 2.0`?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you don't want to use dependency injection? I mean, you could just use the singleton pattern if you really want - I don't see why you'd want to use the `HttpContext` here.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you don't want to use dependency injection? I mean, you could just use the singleton pattern if you really want - I don't see why you'd want to use the `HttpContext` here.

Comment: Just use static property then? Since you don't want to use dependency injection, drawbacks of using static properties won't be a problem for you I guess.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I have many controllers in my application and I need to Inject it in each controller. So better is If I can directly get those values from `HttpContext` is better. Because `HttpContext` is by default available in all controllers

Comment: @Evk - can you please paste code in the answer which use `static` property so I can have better idea and use it. That would be more helpful for me

Comment: But it sounds like the data has nothing to do with the `HttpContext` at all, so why include it there? If you basically want a singleton and don't want the testing and isolation benefits of dependency injection, use the singleton pattern. I wouldn't personally do that myself - I'd use dependency injection to make it clear where you need it, and to enable easy testing - but it's certainly feasible, and makes more sense IMO than using `HttpContext` for something which is unrelated to the actual request.

Comment: You can use base class for this if you dont want to use depency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand the reasoning behind not wanting to inject, you can still use a singleton and access the value from `HttpContext` using this:

```
HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ApplicationLevelData>();
```

To use this function you will have to import `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

You can also create an extension function for this if you like:

```
public static class HttpContextExtensions {
    public static ApplicationLevelData GetAppData(this HttpContext HttpContext)
        => HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ApplicationLevelData>();
}
```

You can now get your `ApplicationLevelData` within any controller by using `HttpContext.GetAppData()`.

Comment: Can you please explain me in details how can I implement it in my project. your little more help would be more helpful for me. Thanks :)

Comment: I have added some more details. I also see you have created the singleton. You simply need to create the class I have shown

Comment: Can you please tell me where do I need to write below line? in which file ?
`HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ApplicationLevelData>();`

Comment: That line can be used in any controller as you had asked in your question. However as long as you are making the class I have shown above, you can ignore that first line

Comment: I got error : Method 'object System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type) dose not have type parameters

Comment: you need to have `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` at the start of the file

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static Guid TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Usage (in any place):

```
var guid = Globals.TestProperty;
```

You said:

> this data will comes from database (only once)

You can also create as `private set`, like this:

```
public static Guid TestProperty { get; private set; }
```

Then it is only possible to set the value inside the class `Globals`, making this sort of a readonly property.

Also, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721832/c-sharp-static-class-constructor) about the constructor. It is a bit different on a `static class`.